# Installed Dreamweaver 5.5 has not any uninstall. How to remove it?

Tags: uninstall, dreamweaver

I'd installed Dreamweaver 5.5 some months ago and now I want to uninstall it. But there is no uninstall file in directory, or even there is nothing in Control Panel -> Programs. There is no Creative suite too. 
How can I uninsatall it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try this tool from Adobe: [Adobe Creative Suite Cleaner Tool](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: As [dave](https://superuser.com/users/146314/dave) pointed out in the comment, please refer to [this article for how to uninstall](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/uninstall-creative-suite-cs5-cs5.html).

Delete the folder in which the application is present. Uninstall does the same thing except for cleaning up some registry entries and some shared application folders under `C:\Users\<username>\`.

Comment: Do you think cleaning up registry is not important?

Comment: Since messing up the OS by deleting the wrong keys in the registry is much more problematic, you can avoid doing it. There are some third-party apps that delete obsolete keys. More information here: http://superuser.com/questions/225892/registry-cleaner-useful-or-not

Comment: And this: http://superuser.com/questions/1900/is-it-worth-cleaning-the-registry

Comment: -1 as this doesn't take any consideration about re-installation. Please see http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/uninstall-creative-suite-cs5-cs5.html which also suggests against this action

Comment: But if you have legal copy, registry settings wont make any problem for you. Only pirated ones get messed up due to old keys........

Comment: Thanks for the correction everyone. Shall I delete this answer or leave it?